# Writing a simple Mac App to start a python document

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I am writing a Mac program in python that will run in terminal, and have a start.command file to start it up:

#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
exec python "$(dirname "$0")/xavier_root/xavier_I-nil-nil.py"

I was wondering though, if there would be a way to create a .app that would start up this program instead, so that I can put it on my dock. Is there any way I can do a simple app that would start up my start.command file, or perform the actions that my start.command file is doing?

Answer (score 2):

Automator is great for this.

Your one-line command, as an automator service, could be run from a keystroke.

You can also make a terminal profile that runs the command when the profile is launched.

You could also use applescript editor and make a (relatively simple) applescript that does the 'do script' command, to run your command.  This gets you an .app.  (A clickable launcher)